# Como criar uma regex para filtrar e deletar arquivos com determinado trecho no nome

Tags: java, regex, arquivo

Estou tentando bolar um jeito de apagar arquivos que o windows duplica, quando se faz múltiplas cópias. Consegui fazer algo, criando o código abaixo:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class FileCreator{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        File f = f = new File(".");
        File[] files = f.listFiles();

        for(File fl : files){
            String fileName = fl.getName();
            if(fileName.contains("Copia - Copia")){
                    System.out.println(fileName);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Criei alguns arquivos, conforme segue o print abaixo:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

E o resutado foi:

```
C:\Users\diego\Desktop\Nova pasta>java FileCreator
File 0 - Copia - Copia.txt
File 10 - Copia - Copia.txt
File 12 - Copia - Copia.txt
File 14 - Copia - Copia.txt
File 16 - Copia - Copia.txt
File 18 - Copia - Copia.txt
File 2 - Copia - Copia.txt
File 4 - Copia - Copia.txt
File 6 - Copia - Copia.txt
File 8 - Copia - Copia.txt
```

Essa forma até me atende, pois basta eu substituir a saida de texto da condição dentro do laço por um simples `fl.delete();` mas gostaria de ter mais controle sobre o que é excluido, utilizando uma regex.

Comecei a fazer algo conforme abaixo, mas não consegui criar uma regex que consiga detectar o "`Copia - Copia`" exatamente no final do nome do arquivo, e então apagá-lo.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("");
    Matcher m;

    f = new File(".");
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    for(File fl : files){
        String fileName = fl.getName();
        m = p.matcher(fileName);
        if(m.find()){
            //fl.delete();
            System.out.println(fileName + " deletado");
        }
    }
```

Como faço uma regex que filtre esses aquivos?

Obs.: detectar a extensão é irrelevante, só preciso detectar o `Copia - Copia` que é como o windows renomeia duplicatas de duplicatas, adicionando no final do nome do arquivo.

<sub>*Se possivel, gostaria de entender o funcionamento da expressão também*</sub>

Comment: Porque você não faz isso: filename.split(".")[0].substring(filename.length-13, filename.length) == "Copia - Copia"

Comment: Achei a expressão aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word

Comment: @Douglas a intenção era aprender utilizando regex porque também tenho um programa automatizador aqui, onde só adiciono uma regex e configuro umas regras na janela e ele faz o resto. Em string eu sei fazer mas acho que a pasta onde vou executar talvez eu não tenha permissão de execução(pasta de rede do trabalho :/)

Comment: @diegofm veja se a explicação ficou clara na edição http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/167965/3635

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex pode ser assim `Copia - Copia.[^.]+$`

Explicação:

```
Copia - Copia\\.[^.]+$
^                ^   ^
1                2   3
```

1. O `Copia - Copia\\.` é a parte que deseja encontrar
2. `[^.]` o sinal de `^` se estiver dentro de `[...]` indica negação, ou seja qualquer caractere dentro de `[^....]` será ignorado no *match*, então após o pontos usei ele para que qualquer coisa possa ser a extensão do arquivo, menos outro ponto.
3. O `$` é o que define que o nome do arquivo (a `String`) deve terminar exatamente conforme o que vier antes, no caso deve terminar com `Copia - Copia.[qualquer extensão]`

> Como alternativa pode usar o `C[oó]pia - C[oó]pia\\.[^.]+$` acaso haja situações com acentos e sem acentos, note que varia se for unicode
>
> O uso ficaria algo como `final Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("C[oó]pia - C[oó]pia\\.[^.]+$");`

Um exemplo com `List<String>` para testar:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class Exemplo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("Copia - Copia\\.[^.]+$");

        List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();

        files.add("File 123 - Copia.txt");
        files.add("File 10 - Copia - Copia.java");
        files.add("File 12 - Copia.java");
        files.add("File 14 - Copia - Copia.txt");
        files.add("File 16 - Copia.txt");
        files.add("File 18 - Copia - Copia.log");
        files.add("File 2 - Copia.txt");
        files.add("File 4 - Copia.log");
        files.add("File 6 - Copia - Copia.txt");
        files.add("File 8 - Copia.txt");

        for (String file : files)
        {
            if (regex.matcher(file).find())
            {
                System.out.println("Encontrado: " + file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Exemplo no http://ideone.com/Ph7CJC

---

Também é possível usar `String.matches`, mas com ele será preciso adicionar `.*` na frente, pois por algum motivo ele ignora se não for feito isto, ficando assim `.*Copia - Copia\\.[^.]+$`. Todavia como o @VictorStafusa disse, talvez isto possa comprometer um pouco a performance, dependendo de quantas vezes irá executar (ainda não pude confirmar)

Explicação:

```
.*Copia - Copia\\.[^.]+$
^  ^               ^   ^
1  2               3   4
```

Ficaria algo como:

```
for (String file : files)
{
    if (file.matches("Copia - Copia\\.[^.]+$"))
    {
        System.out.println("Encontrado: " + file);
    }
}
```

1. `.*` procura qualquer (grupo de) caractere(s) que vierem antes do texto desejado
2. O `Copia - Copia\\.` é a parte que deseja encontrar
3. `[^.]` o sinal de `^` se estiver dentro de `[...]` indica negação, ou seja qualquer caractere dentro de `[^....]` será ignorado no match, então após o pontos usei ele para que qualquer coisa possa ser a extensão do arquivo, menos outro ponto.
4. O `$` é o que define que o nome do arquivo (a `String`) deve terminar exatamente conforme o que vier antes, no caso deve terminar com `[qualquer caractere]Copia - Copia.[qualquer extensão]`

> Como alternativa pode usar o `.*C[oó]pia - C[oó]pia\\.[^.]+$` acaso haja situações com acentos e sem acentos, note que varia se for unicode
>
> O uso ficaria algo como `if (file.matches("C[oó]pia - C[oó]pia\\.[^.]+$")) {`

Comment: Na verdade, `String.matches` utiliza `Pattern` por debaixo dos panos([1](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/jdk/file/906d416fdf75/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l2120), [2](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/jdk/file/906d416fdf75/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#l1133) e [3](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/jdk/file/906d416fdf75/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#l1054)). Ao usar o `Pattern` diretamente, ele só será compilado uma vez. Com o `match` dentro de um loop, ele ser (re)compilado várias vezes, tendo um desempenho inferior.

Comment: @VictorStafusa vou ajustar, eu acreditava que o Java assim como outras linguagens geravam um cache do `Pattern` (um exemplo é o PHP), mas por via das duvidas (questão de versão x compatibilidade) segui suas dicas, editado.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte expressão regular:

```
Pattern.compile("Copia - Copia\\.[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$");
```

Onde:

- `Copia - Copia` é o texto que você está procurando;
- `\\.` é o caractere literal `.`. O normal seria apenas `\` porém como a expressão está em uma `string` temos que escapá-la uma vez;
- `[a-zA-Z]` delimita que o caractere deve estar entre `a` e `z` ou `A` e `Z`;
- `{3, 4}` é relacionado a quantidade de caracteres, que deve ser de 3 ou 4;
- `$` quer dizer que é no final da `string`;

Ou seja:

> Procura o texto `Copia - Copia` seguido de um `.`, 3 ou 4 letras de `a` a `Z` no final de uma `string`;

Comment: Ao invés de `[.]`, use `\\.`

Comment: @VictorStafusa quals eria a diferença nesse caso?

Comment: É que a notação começando com `\\ ` é a forma padrão de se fazer *quoting*, enquanto que o `[]` é usado para *grouping*. Ou seja, enquanto que `\\.` funciona porque foi projetado para funcionar assim, `[.]` funciona mais por sorte, coincidência ou acidente. Por exemplo, se fosse `[-]` já não funcionaria, enquanto que `\\-` continuaria funcionando.

Comment: @VictorStafusa entendi, vou alterar a resposta

Answer (score 1):

Use esssa expressão:

> (Copia - Copia)

Os parênteses definem um grupo de caracteres a serem 'capturados' da string.

Entre nesse site http://regexr.com/3eoeg para ver funcionando.

Comment: Seguindo o comentário do @CleitonOliveira, essa regex funcionou somente ao utilizar apenas  `(Copia - Copia)`, removendo as barras e o g.

Answer (score 0):

```
String trechoParaRemover = "(Copia - Copia)";
fileName = filename.replace(trechoParaRemover,"");
```

Só isso resolveria seu caso, não acredito que precise de uma expressão regular nem do delete().

Comment: Acho que você não leu o enunciado. preciso identificar o padrao(com regex) e deletar o arquivo na pasta, não renomear o arquivo.

Comment: Lamento não ter sido mais claro. Uma prática simples e eficiente é renomear o arquivo com o resultado da substituição da string completamente.
Li que você quer fazer com regex para dominá-lo. O @Douglas usou o melhor site para isso, o regexr. No seu caso, bastaria colocar o regex que ele indicou na seguinte linha:
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Copia - Copia)");

Particularmente eu prefiro usar aspas em vez de barras, e o "g" é dispensável no seu caso pois não é preciso fazer uma leitura global, sendo apenas uma string pequena a ser validada.

Comment: Puxa, é verdade, removendo as barras e o /g a regex funciona corretamente. Sou muito leigo em regex, pensei que o /g era pra filtrar algo mais no final do texto, vivendo e aprendendo, obrigado pelo esclarecimento :D

Comment: @diegofm final de string é $

Comment: @Sorack no caso dele, a string ainda contém .txt no final. O $ não vai capturar o trecho que ele quer.